# Problem with JSON return to main function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, function, variables

I’m new in JS, I have a problem with my code:

```
tbotping();

function tbotping () {
  var MikroNode = require('mikronode');

  var device = new MikroNode('IP');

  //device.setDebug(MikroNode.DEBUG);

  device.connect()
.then(([login])=>login('username','password'))
.then(function(conn) {
  
  conn.closeOnDone(true);
  
  var ping = conn.openChannel();
  ping.closeOnDone(true);
  console.log('Get ping');
  ping.write('/ping',{'address':'77.88.8.8','count':'3'});

  ping.data
  .subscribe(function (data) {
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(myJSON);

    });
  });
};
```

The code works correctly, but I can’t understand, how can I get data from myJSON for return from main function to use. Now I can only see json data in console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can't, because the data that will arrive later on (after the ping was completed) can't time-travel back to when the function returned. The whole code (including your main function) needs to be converted to be asynchronous.

Comment: Thx guys! If someone could help make my code to asynchronous, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

> If someone could help make my code to asynchronous

You need to encapsulate your content of function `tbotping()` in a `Promise` object like :

```
function tbotping() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //Your previous code
    });
};
```

`resolve` parameter is a function. It is used to return result for an asynchronous function. In your case you need to return `myJSON` data. So you just need to add this line of code after `console.log(myJSON)` :

```
resolve(myJSON);
```

`reject` parameter is a function too. It is used to throw an occurred error for example when something bad appears on `device.connect()`. We will use it later.

Then, how main process can retrieve value of `myJSON` which is returned by `resolve`? Actually, `tbotping()` return a `Promise`object now. This object has a method called `then()`. When this method is called, all content of Promise is executed and we can retrieve the `myJSON` data via this code :

```
tbotping().then(function(myJSON) {
    //Use myJSON
})
```

You can notice that :

```
device.connect()
    .then(([login])=>login('username','password'))
```

uses Promise mechanism too. Actually, there is another method `catch()` which allows to retrieve error from `reject` function. Your code becomes :

```
tbotping().then(function(myJSON) {
    //Use myJSON
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Use error
});
```

And because `device.connect()` can potentially has error you can throw it like :

```
device.connect()
    .then(([login])=>login('username','password'))
    .then(function(conn) {
        //Code
    }).catch(function(error) {
        reject(error);
    });
```

But it is awkward to manage `then()` and `catch()` every time. To simplify, you can use combo `async/await`. First we need to tell JS that `function(resolve, reject)` is an asynchrone function by adding `async` keyword :

```
return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
```

For each `then()`, you replace it by `await` :

```
/*

This code :

device.connect()
.then(([login]) => login('username', 'password'))
.then(function (conn) {
    //Code
})

becomes :
*/

const [login] = await device.connect();
conn = await login('username', 'password');
```

and

```
/*

This code :

tbotping().then(function(myJSON) {
//Use myJSON
});

becomes :
*/

const myJSON = await tbotping();
```

For each `catch()`, you replace it by `try catch` JS syntax. So, your final code becomes :

```
const MikroNode = require('mikronode');

function tbotping() {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            const device = new MikroNode('IP');

            const [login] = await device.connect()
            const conn = await login('username', 'password');
            conn.closeOnDone(true);

            const ping = conn.openChannel();
            ping.closeOnDone(true);
            console.log('Get ping');
            ping.write('/ping', { 'address': '77.88.8.8', 'count': '3' });

            ping.data
                .subscribe(function (data) {
                    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
                    resolve(myJSON);
                });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};


(async function() {//We need to create an anonymous function because await can be only runned in asynchrone bloc code
    try {
        const myJSON = await tbotping();
        console.log(myJSON);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();//And don't forget to call the anonymous function by terminate it with "()"
```

Yes, it is more difficult to understand but you need to practice and check on the internet what are `Promise`, `async` and `await`. ^^

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my hero! This promise, async and await very hard to understand, but now i can do it!